# Giving input separated by spaces

Tags: java

Input:

```
1 10
```

How can I provide a space between two inputs so that compiler can take both the inputs differently.

I tried to use

```
st1=in.nextInt();
in.next();
st2=in.nextInt();
```

Comment: take the whole string as one. split the string by space. convert string results to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line will give you a `String` array containing the two numbers as strings:

```
String[] numbersFromUser = in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Assuming that the user properly formats the input.

This would of course also work for a number of arguments greater than 2.

You can then go on to convert `numbersFromUser[0]` and `numbersFromUser[1]` into the `int` values you need:

```
int st1 = Integer.valueOf(numbersFromUser[0]).intValue();
int st2 = Integer.valueOf(numbersFromUser[1]).intValue();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i m using the snippet provided i'm getting NumberFormateException

Comment: What are the exact values of `numbersFromUser[0]` and `numbersFromUser[1]` in this particular case? Have you worked with a debugger before?

Comment: The values are 1 and 10. And i'm not familier with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `in.next();` call. `nextInt()` already "ignores" whitespaces. And there is no need to create an array by using `split()` and to convert the number "manually". Just let the Scanner handle this by using `nextInt()` like you do already:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("1 10 9 5");
while(s.hasNextInt()) {
    int number = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

The good thing about that is, that you won't get a `NumberFormatException` like in the other answers if the user does not provide numbers (e.g. `a b c`).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data = line.split("\s");
first = data[0];
second = data[1];
third = data[2];
System.out.println(first)
System.out.println(second);
System.out.println(third);
```

Input:

```
1 5 6
```

Output:

```
1
5
6
```